# Formatted date as String converted to date wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I am trying to store date in DB using the current timezone.
I have used library `date-fns-tz` When I convert the date as a string is okay, but when I want to create that string as a Date it is still a problem.

```
    const date = new Date();
const date_string = formatInTimeZone(
  date,
  "Europe/Rome",
  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
);

console.log(date_string); //2022-04-16 11:46:28  (Right time)
const current_date = new Date(date_string); // 2022-04-16T09:46:28.000Z   (Converted to 2h back)
```

Comment: It's 2 hours back, not 3. And it's important because Rome is in UTC+2 timezone. The final time you see is UTC.

Comment: How to make in the UTC+2

Comment: The time is correct. It's just the display that gives you UTC. If you get the local time *and you're in the correct timezone* you'd get  11 o'clock. Otherwise you need to *format the display for a timezone you want*. Date objects don't come with a time zone themselves

Comment: I understand that part, that is why I am creating a date based on the date_string which is in the correct timezone. The problem is why is it not getting that date correctly

Comment: Because 9 o'clock UTC is EXACTLY THE SAME as 11 o'clock UTC+2. Date objects *do not have a time zone*. They store the time according to UTC. Different modes of display might or might not apply the local time zone. The one you looked at didn't. That's it.